# Auto multiply two column in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

HI,

I need to calculate values of two textboxex in gridview and display the result in the third textbox using javascript as soon as the value entered in second textbox.

my textbox fields are: Quantity and Price
The result should be displayed in Total.

that is, (Total)Value= Quantity * Rate.

I have tried this,
CODE BEHIND:C#

```
protected void gvPOItms__RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {            
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtQty");
        TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtRate");
        TextBox txt3 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue");

        txt1.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')";
        txt2.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
 function multiplication(tx1,txt2,txt3)
        {
        //Your logic for multiplication
        var Qty=document.getElementById(txt1).value;
        var Rate=document.getElementById(txt2).value;
        document.getElementById(txt3).value=Qty*Rate;       
        }
    </script>
```

Markup Page:

But, i couldn't get the answer, its not throwing any error.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: you may help us by providing a live example at, for example, http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change string to int (as value of any textbox returns string) before multiplication :)

try this :-

```
txt1.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text) + "','" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text) + "','" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt3.ClientID) + "')";
txt2.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text) + "','" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text) + "','" +  Convert.ToInt32(txt3.ClientID) + "')";
```

In script :-

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
 function multiplication(Qty,Rate,txt3)
    {
    //Your logic for multiplication

    document.getElementById(txt3).value=Qty*Rate;       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Anukush roy, thanks for your good suggestion..i just found it working fine....and sorry for late intimate.......

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines of code

```
txt1.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')";
txt2.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')";
```

Use Add method instead

```
txt1.Attributes.Add("onKeyup", "javascript: return multiplication('" +
     txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')");
txt2.Attributes.Add("onKeyup", "javascript: return multiplication('" +
     txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')");
```

and also do `parseInt()` in javascript

```
var Qty  = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value);
var Rate = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt2).value);
```