# Multiply Gridview Texbox Rows using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

[image]

This is my Gridview .i have to multiply MRP and Quantity (MRP*Quantity) on Quantity Keyup Event display at Total Textbox .

I have tried this

```
 function myFunction() {
        var quantity = document.getElementById('<%=txtquantity.ClientID %>').value;

        var MRP = document.getElementById('<%=txtMRPCode.ClientID %>').value;

        var total = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(MRP);

        document.getElementById('<%=txtTotal.ClientID %>').value = total;

        var tax = document.getElementById('<%=txtTax.ClientID %>').value;

        var GrandTotal = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(tax);
        document.getElementById('<%=txtGrandTotal.ClientID %>').value = GrandTotal;
        return false;
    }
```

but I couldn't find the Controls value because controls are inside the Gridview .
how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Each item in a row will inherit from the grid, that's why you're not able to pinpoint the control.  Look up how to get the ID of controls in a gridview.

Comment: Either you can attach a javascript function on these text box keyup events in the GridView RowDataBound event. Or the other way is assign a unique class names too these text boxes and use jquery to select and bind the javascript function to it.

Comment: [SO Previous Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441892/auto-multiply-two-column-in-gridview) seems to be same,try it, may help